# Line magic function `%%R` not found

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm, rpy2

I am using Mac OS Catalina, PyCharm with Jupyter notebook. I am trying to pass a variable with %%R from python code

```
import rpy2.rinterface

%load_ext rpy2.ipython

print(rpy2.__version__)
v=2

%%R -i v
print(v)
```

I receive this error:

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%%R` not found.
```

Python 3.7.5
rpy2 3.2.2
R 3.5.1
What can be the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Tested the snippet (with `%load_ext`) in PyCharm 2019.3 (Professional Edition) on Linux and it worked as expected. What is your PyCharm version? My versions are rpy2: 3.2.2 Python 3.7.5, R 3.6.1.

Comment: PyCharm is 2019.3 (Professional Edition) the only difference is R. Mine is 3.5.1. I just do not see any valid reason for this really. I tried to uninstall and install things also but it is just not going away...

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217932/6646912) below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%%R` is a cell magic, not a line magic. You need to place it in a new cell. In PyCharm cells are created using `#%%` comment mark. The correct use in the PyCharm environment is:

```
#%%

%load_ext rpy2.ipython
v = 2

#%%

%%R -i v
print(v)
```

Cell magics start with two percent signs (`%%cell_magic_name`) and line magics start with one percent sign (`%line_magic_name`). Your error message indicates that you tried to use the cell magic in a place different than the beginning of the cell - and your snippet does not have (PyCharm specific) cell separators which confirm that this is the case.

There are both (identically named) cell and line R magics provided by rpy2 (with the number of % signs being the only difference), but the cell magic has to be placed at the very beginning of a cell - the code within this cell will be interpreted as R.

Comment: "%%R must be at very beginning of cell". Even comments placed above it may break it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider loading the relevant Jupyter extension with `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` before trying to use the "R magic"
(see https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/interactive.html#usage )

Comment: Yes. It is weird, right?

When I use print(rpy2.__version__), it works and writes version as 3.2.2. I just do not understand what the problem is really :( Any way to test what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If using only Jupyter, just make sure you run

```
%%R -i v
print(v)
```

in a separate cell, and do not add any code -not even # comments- above `%%R`.

So the correct usage is:

Cell 1:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

v = 2
```

Cell 2:

```
%%R -i v
print(v)
```

---

If you put everything in the same cell, it won't work.

This does not work:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

v = 2

%%R -i v
print(v)
```

```
UsageError: Line magic function `%%R` not found.
```

I think the reason is the same as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217932/4819747).